# Where is code to perform the fake quantize in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I would like to make a custom quantizer (not stardard 8 bit) in TensorFlow.

I've gone through the code in `tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\quantize\python` and can see how the nodes are added, but I would like to modify how the `tf.fake_quantize_with_min_max_vars` function calculates that outputs.

I cannot seem to find the code that actually does the 32 bit accumulate and downsampling to 8 bit.  Can anyone point me to where this code resides?

Comment: I can't seem to find the `tf.fake_quantize_with_min_max_vars` function. Can you please specify in where to find it?

Comment: This is the function in the docs ...

[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/fake_quant_with_min_max_args)

I'm looking for the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The code that does the actual quantization of the values is in C++, in this function here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/fake_quant_ops_functor.h#L79

It's not particularly easy to modify, since you'll need to rebuild TensorFlow to get the changes, but hopefully that gives you a start.